# How do I use the offset path function to create ligatures with even white space where they overlap like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, text, logo

[image: ligature logo]

The tutorial I saw has he guy use the expand feature then use the offset path feature and then he uses a tool to remove the expanded areas and create this effect. I have been trying to figure it our and have no clue how he did it.

Comment: Please clarify how far you got. You got the characters? You managed to expand? You managed to offset?

Comment: Hi. Wlecome to GDSE. You could use the Shape Builder tool to remove those pieces. Try that.